# Filter on a mongo document and project specific fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am quite a beginner in MongoDb. Tried a lot but stuck on one query.
Please find a sample mongo document on the given below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc158a60566e14c5190db72"), 
    "hotel_id" : NumberInt(45), 
    "plans" : [
        {
            "plan_type" : "AP", 
            "sub_plans" : [
                {
                    "channels" : [
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "status" : "Pending", 
                            "is_active" : false, 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "non_veg_available" : null, 
                            "oyo_commission" : 20.0, 
                            "ep_price_reduction" : null, 
                            "salesforce_id" : "a0Y280000023LFwEAM", 
                            "breakfast_start_time" : null, 
                            "breakfast_end_time" : null, 
                            "lunch_start_time" : null, 
                            "lunch_end_time" : null, 
                            "dinner_start_time" : null, 
                            "dinner_end_time" : null, 
                            "created_at" : NumberLong(1468577718000), 
                            "updated_at" : NumberLong(1481074321000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "occupancy" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "guest_type" : null, 
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(400), 
                                    "non_veg_price" : null, 
                                    "additional_non_veg_price" : null, 
                                    "discount" : null
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "status" : "Pending", 
                            "is_active" : false, 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "non_veg_available" : null, 
                            "oyo_commission" : 20.0, 
                            "ep_price_reduction" : null, 
                            "salesforce_id" : "a0W28000004GqL4", 
                            "breakfast_start_time" : "7:30", 
                            "breakfast_end_time" : "10:00", 
                            "lunch_start_time" : "12:30", 
                            "lunch_end_time" : "15:00", 
                            "dinner_start_time" : "19:00", 
                            "dinner_end_time" : "22:30", 
                            "created_at" : NumberLong(1505516604000), 
                            "updated_at" : NumberLong(1505516604000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "occupancy" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "guest_type" : null, 
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(425), 
                                    "non_veg_price" : NumberInt(425), 
                                    "additional_non_veg_price" : 0.0, 
                                    "discount" : null
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "status" : "Pending", 
                            "is_active" : false, 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "non_veg_available" : null, 
                            "oyo_commission" : 20.0, 
                            "ep_price_reduction" : null, 
                            "salesforce_id" : "a0W28000004GqL4", 
                            "breakfast_start_time" : "7:30", 
                            "breakfast_end_time" : "10:00", 
                            "lunch_start_time" : "12:30", 
                            "lunch_end_time" : "15:00", 
                            "dinner_start_time" : "19:00", 
                            "dinner_end_time" : "22:30", 
                            "created_at" : NumberLong(1505709978000), 
                            "updated_at" : NumberLong(1542162045000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "occupancy" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "guest_type" : null, 
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(425), 
                                    "non_veg_price" : NumberInt(425), 
                                    "additional_non_veg_price" : 0.0, 
                                    "discount" : null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ], 
                    "sub_plan_type" : "Standard", 
                    "is_sub_plan_default" : false
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "plan_type" : "EP", 
            "sub_plans" : [
                {
                    "channels" : [
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "status" : "Pending", 
                            "is_active" : false, 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "non_veg_available" : null, 
                            "oyo_commission" : null, 
                            "ep_price_reduction" : NumberInt(80), 
                            "salesforce_id" : "a0Y280000023LG1EAM", 
                            "breakfast_start_time" : null, 
                            "breakfast_end_time" : null, 
                            "lunch_start_time" : null, 
                            "lunch_end_time" : null, 
                            "dinner_start_time" : null, 
                            "dinner_end_time" : null, 
                            "created_at" : NumberLong(1468577718000), 
                            "updated_at" : NumberLong(1481074321000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "occupancy" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "guest_type" : null, 
                                    "veg_price" : null, 
                                    "non_veg_price" : null, 
                                    "additional_non_veg_price" : null, 
                                    "discount" : null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ], 
                    "sub_plan_type" : "Standard", 
                    "is_sub_plan_default" : false
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "plan_type" : "MAP", 
            "sub_plans" : [
                {
                    "channels" : [
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "status" : "Pending", 
                            "is_active" : false, 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "non_veg_available" : null, 
                            "oyo_commission" : 20.0, 
                            "ep_price_reduction" : null, 
                            "salesforce_id" : "a0Y280000023LG6EAM", 
                            "breakfast_start_time" : null, 
                            "breakfast_end_time" : null, 
                            "lunch_start_time" : null, 
                            "lunch_end_time" : null, 
                            "dinner_start_time" : null, 
                            "dinner_end_time" : null, 
                            "created_at" : NumberLong(1468577718000), 
                            "updated_at" : NumberLong(1481074321000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "occupancy" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "guest_type" : null, 
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(200), 
                                    "non_veg_price" : null, 
                                    "additional_non_veg_price" : null, 
                                    "discount" : null
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "status" : "Pending", 
                            "is_active" : false, 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "non_veg_available" : null, 
                            "oyo_commission" : 20.0, 
                            "ep_price_reduction" : null, 
                            "salesforce_id" : "a0W28000004GqL4", 
                            "breakfast_start_time" : "7:30", 
                            "breakfast_end_time" : "10:00", 
                            "lunch_start_time" : "12:30", 
                            "lunch_end_time" : "15:00", 
                            "dinner_start_time" : "19:00", 
                            "dinner_end_time" : "22:30", 
                            "created_at" : NumberLong(1505709978000), 
                            "updated_at" : NumberLong(1541476001000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "occupancy" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "guest_type" : null, 
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(225), 
                                    "non_veg_price" : NumberInt(225), 
                                    "additional_non_veg_price" : 0.0, 
                                    "discount" : null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ], 
                    "sub_plan_type" : "Standard", 
                    "is_sub_plan_default" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want only selected fields if:
hotel id is 45, price of occupancy 1, is_active is false and status is Pending and plan type is in ['AP', 'EP'].
Desired output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc158a60566e14c5190db72"), 
    "hotel_id" : NumberInt(45), 
    "plans" : [
        {
            "plan_type" : "AP", 
            "sub_plans" : [
                {
                    "channels" : [
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(425)
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "veg_price" : NumberInt(425)
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ], 
                    "sub_plan_type" : "Standard", 
                    "is_sub_plan_default" : false
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "plan_type" : "EP", 
            "sub_plans" : [
                {
                    "channels" : [
                        {
                            "channel_name" : "default", 
                            "start_date" : NumberLong(1468521000000), 
                            "end_date" : NumberLong(1901125800000), 
                            "prices" : [
                                {
                                    "veg_price" : null, 
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ], 
                    "sub_plan_type" : "Standard", 
                    "is_sub_plan_default" : false
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

My Query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "hotel_id": 45,
  "plans.plan_type": {$in : ["AP", "EP"]},
  "plans.sub_plans.channels.prices.occupancy": 1,
  "plans.sub_plans.channels.is_active": false,
  "plans.sub_plans.channels.status": "Pending"
})
```

**Note** - I need to search in only one document where hotel id is 45.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for a query like this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$plans",

  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$hotel_id",
      "hotel_id": {
        "$first": "$hotel_id"
      },
      "plans": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$plans.plan_type",
                    "AP"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$plans.plan_type",
                    "EP"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "plan_type": "$plans.plan_type",
              "sub_plans": "$plans.sub_plans",
              "sub_plan_type": "$plans.sub_plan_type",
              "is_sub_plan_default": "$is_sub_plan_default"
            },
            null
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "hotel_id": 1,
      "plans": {
        "$filter": {
          input: "$plans",
          as: "plan",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$plan",
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: First one is not working and second one is returning no document. Please suggest.

Comment: See the first one at work on mongo playground linked below.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/u6V_6lFGet7

Comment: Modified the answer to match hotel_id as "NumberInt(45)" instead of "45". How does that work?

Comment: It seems to work on the setup created on mongoplayground. What's different?

Comment: For first, It is not working see.
https://snipboard.io/HCyw6Q.jpg

Comment: Right, think I get how you mean not working now. See https://mongoplayground.net/p/-8-M8ppRhRW

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply aggregation.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([

    {
        "$match":{
            "hotel_id": 45,
            "plans.plan_type": "AP",
            "plans.sub_plans.channels.prices.occupancy": 1,
            "plans.sub_plans.channels.is_active": false,
            "plans.sub_plans.channels.status": "Pending"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "hotel_id":"$hotel_id",
            "plans":"plans"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the .reply.
But your query is containing results of all plans. I want only the "AP" plan. Kindly have a look and suggest further.

Comment: ```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "hotel_id": 45,
            "plans.sub_plans.channels.prices.occupancy": 1,
            "plans.sub_plans.channels.is_active": false,
            "plans.sub_plans.channels.status": "Pending"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match":{
            "plans.plan_type": {
                "$in":['AP']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "hotel_id": "$hotel_id",
            "plans": "plans"
        }
    }
])


```

Comment: Kindly check again. It's not working. https://mongoplayground.net/p/s20pxAK6vE0